# WP8 Emulator is not displaying contents of map

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8-emulator

i am developing a windows phone 8 app, i have placed a map control on the xaml page, while running it in emulator only a blue square box displays in place of map.

Output screen : https://docs.google.com/file/d/0By0Y-Dca1cKjVG1QQUY3MVBQcFk/edit?usp=sharing

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Maps"
    x:Class="MapTestApp.MainPage"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Bing Map" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <maps:Map />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Map MyMap = new Map();
            MyMap.Center = new GeoCoordinate(47.6097, -122.3331);
            MyMap.ZoomLevel = 3;
            MyMap.LandmarksEnabled = true;
            MyMap.PedestrianFeaturesEnabled = true;
            MyMap.CartographicMode = MapCartographicMode.Aerial;
            ContentPanel.Children.Add(MyMap);
        }
```

Comment: Looks like it shows you the ocean. Can you zoom out, or srcoll the map?

Comment: i have set zoomlevel to 3, so at that zoomlevel i don't think so there is ocean.

Comment: i have tried scrolling, but i didn't find any change in the map. so i can't say that it is scrolling.

Comment: @AntonSizikov hy i have added pushpins on the map to check whether it is scrolling or not, i found pushpins are moving while scrolling, but on the blue background.

Comment: You can remove `<maps:Map />` from the xaml, since you are not using it and you create another instance in code. I don't think that's the reason why it is not working, but just to comment.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added capabilities.

Go to WMAppManifest - Capabilities and Check:

ID_CAP_LOCATION
ID_CAP_MAP

Comment: i have already checked them in capabilities. but didn't find any change.

Comment: are you doing WP7 or WP8 application?

Comment: it is WP8.0 application.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. This is probably caused because the emulator doesn't have network connection. You can check your emulator's network connection by opening a web browser on it and navigating to a page.

If your emulator doesn't have network connection, it can be because of different causes. You may find following documentation on MSDM helpful:

[Troubleshooting the Windows Phone 8 Emulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681694%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

I have tried your code on a real device with network connection and it appears to work correctly. This is what I see:

[image]

Comment: web pages are opening on my emulator, so there is no issue of network on my emulator,

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the map zoom level, it might happen that it is showing you the oceans.

Also check the manifest if you have granted Internet access capability and Positioning capabilities.